# Looking up values in third column by two criteria

Tags: excel

I have a list similar to this one:

```
NO | Cat1 | Cat2 |   | Crit1 | Crit2 |
---|------|------|   |   A   |   O   |
5  |   A  |   O  |
3  |   K  |   Y  |
6  |   K  |   Y  |
7  |   F  |   K  |
8  |   A  |   O  |
9  |   J  |   H  |
10 |   K  |   Y  |
5  |   F  |   T  |
50 |   A  |   O  |
8  |   L  |   E  |
1  |   R  |   D  |
```

Based on two criteria I want a dynamic list which changes everytime the content are changed or the criteria are changed.

If criteria is `A O` then the list should be as below,

```
|List|
|----|
| 5  |
| 8  |
| 50 |
```

If any other criteria is selected the list will be longer or shorter and if nothing is present it is shown as a blank cell.
I have tried some `MATCH` and `INDEX` formulas but I cannot make it work correctly.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LookUpList;MATCH(0;COUNTIF(NewList;LookUpList)+IF(Cat1<>Crit1;1;0)+IF(Cat2<>Crit2;1;0);0));"")
```

Comment: avoid using pictures for tables if possible, use code markup and formatting with `|` and `-` instead

Comment: Unlike google-sheet's arrayformula, you will have to extend the formula down through sufficient rows that you can catch all possible matches.

Comment: Should be the numbers be sorted or in the order that they appear?

Comment: @user10735198 I know that. It is the formula I have as a problem and I know that it is an arrayformula ;)

Comment: @user10735198 In any way they appear. I believe I would use the normal Filter-function to sort them.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted ascending:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,7,A$2:A$12/((B$2:B$12=G$1)*(C$2:C$12=G$2)),ROW(1:1)), "")
```

Ordered by row:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(A:A)/((B$1:B$12=G$1)*(C$1:C$12=G$2)), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

Pick one formula then fill down for subsequent matches.

[image]

Comment: Neat solution but you are aware that it can only return numbers. Not text and not a mix only numbers. If I could expect a mix of text and numbers is that doable?

Comment: That may be true for the Sorted option but not for the Ordered version.